# What's happening with tag searches?

Tags: support, search

If I click a tag I follow from the main page, I get no results:

[image]

This isn't happening on other SE sites. What's up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It says it right there :-)

> You are on the Featured tab. 
>   There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment.
>   Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?

You are probably looking at [`https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/venice/?sort=featured`](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/venice/?sort=featured), that's why you don't see anything. Remove the last bit and everything works as advertised.

Don't sweat it, I have been stumped by this once or twice before as well. :-)

Comment: but I wasn't on the featured tab on purpose. I just clicked a tag link elsewhere. I tried this on lots of tag links and they all lead there. On other sites that's not what happens

Comment: BTW the URL of that shot is http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/venice

Comment: @KateGregory: From a bit of playing around, it seems to remember the last tab you were at when looking at tags. So if the previous tag you looked at was "featured", then when you look at another one, it would still be on the "featured" tag. You can always switch to another tab, but I agree it's somewhat unexpected. .

Comment: FWIW it works exactly like on other SE sites (just  tested on Android-SE).

Comment: That was it! Very counterintuitive! Thanks!

Comment: @KateGregory this bites even me; we really need to take another look at its usability.